# Box sdk python jwt + How to make successive calls using jwt auth

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, jwt

1. A website which has a link Box to show the Box files and folders.
2. When clicked on to the link, It authenticated with JWT (authenticate_instance) and then a particular user gets authenticated using JWT (authenticate_app_user) which returns me an access_token.
3. using client methods I can fetch the files and folders for listing.
4. Now, If I again click on Box link then whole procedure is repeated, I don't want this. Instead it should use the access_token returned by authenticate_app_user.
5. How can I make calls to the client methods (e.g. user, folder, file) using this access_token (made the authentication already)?

Comment: I am using python box-sdk for this.

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far? To help us help you, please add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Problem is resolved, henceforth I will remember this adding a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example